# How to know when data.addGeoJson() has finished rendering feature in Google Maps API V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there an event or other way to determine when the objects are rendered after adding them via `map.data.addGeoJson()`?

I tried the `addfeature` and `setgeometry` events but `addfeature` is fired (324 times) before `idle` and `tilesloaded` and both of those are fired before the rendering even starts. `setgeometry` does not fire at all.

I need to automate taking a screen cap of the map but I need to know when everything is fully rendered before I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The technique I used is to count how many features I am adding to the google maps and then read the DOM to see if they have all shown up.

You first need to examine the DOM to find the elements and some properties that are unique to your feature. In my case they were markers with custom icons so I could use the src tag:

```
<img alt="" src="images/colour008s.png" draggable="false" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; user-select: none; border: 0px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; max-width: none; width: 22px; height: 34px;">
```

After loading the JSON, I set up an interval to see if they have shown up and there are at least as many as I expect:

```
timerId = setInterval(function () {
    var points = document.querySelectorAll('img[src="images/colour008s.png"]');
    if (points.length >= totalPoints) {
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        console.log("All points loaded");
    }
}, 250);
```

This is working quite well so far.